# Grouped-By DataFrame: Use column-values in current and previous row in Function

Tags: python, pandas, apply, pandas-groupby, pandas-apply

I've got a dataframe with this kind of structure:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.distance import vincenty

data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2 , 3],
        'coord': [[10.1, 30.3], [10.5, 32.3], [11.1, 31.3],
                  [10.1, 30.3], [10.5, 32.3], [61, 29.1]],
       }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

This is how it looks:

```
           coord    id
0   [10.1, 30.3]    1
1   [10.5, 32.3]    2
2   [11.1, 31.3]    3
3   [10.1, 30.3]    1
4   [10.5, 32.3]    2
5   [61, 29.1]      3
```

Now, I want to group by `id`. Then, I want to use the current and previous row of `coords`. These should be used in a function to compute the distance between the two coordinates:

This is what I've tried:

```
df.groupby('id')['coord'].apply(lambda x: vincenty(x, x.shift(1)))
```

[`vincenty(x,y)`](https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/1.10.0/#module-geopy.distance) expects `x` like (10, 20) and the same for `y` and returns a float.

Obviously, this does not work. The function receives two Series objects instead of the two lists. So probably using `x.values.tolist()` should be the next step. However, my understanding of things ends here. Hence, I'd appreciate any ideas on how to tackle this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.shift.html) column per group and then apply function with filter out `NaN`s rows:

```
def vincenty(x, y):
    print (x,y)
    return x + y

df['new'] = df.groupby('id')['coord'].shift()

m = df['new'].notnull()
df.loc[m, 'out'] = df.loc[m, :].apply(lambda x: vincenty(x['coord'], x['new']), axis=1)
print (df)
          coord  id           new                       out
0  [10.1, 30.3]   1           NaN                       NaN
1  [10.5, 32.3]   2           NaN                       NaN
2  [11.1, 31.3]   3           NaN                       NaN
3  [10.1, 30.3]   1  [10.1, 30.3]  [10.1, 30.3, 10.1, 30.3]
4  [10.5, 32.3]   2  [10.5, 32.3]  [10.5, 32.3, 10.5, 32.3]
5    [61, 29.1]   3  [11.1, 31.3]    [61, 29.1, 11.1, 31.3]
```

Comment: Those don't work: indexing with str will only return the first value of the coordinates. But two lists of two values are expected by the function. Maybe this was not clear from my original description. I've edited it to clarify.

Comment: I get it. But what happends for first NaNs?

Comment: Those can be skipped / be NaNs. These are the starting points. So it doesn't make sense to calculate a distance for them yet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That solves it for me!
I'm wondering if there is a simpler / one line solution.

Comment: Hard question, I have no idea. But with `vincenty` function I find only this. `NaN`s complicated it a lot.